# Excel vba reverse for loop stepping beyond end value

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am debugging the code below. when I loop through it, I notice that `row_j` has a value of 1, despite `For row_j = LastRow_date_new To 2 Step -1`.

I want the minimum `row_j` value to be 2 as there is no data in row 1. The values in  `SearchCol` are dates in the format `20/01/2015  09:15:00`, with no gaps or null values.

`row_j` is used to set `End_row` which is passed to `Copy_to_b` and propagates errors there.

Can anyone see where my problem is coming from?

Also, can you recommend a way to **exit the loop when the desired value to match `Date_end` is met**?

Thank you

```
Sub select_date_range(LastCol As Long, LastRow_date_new As Long, DateMax As Date, Date_end As Date)
Dim SearchCol As Integer
Dim row_i As Integer
Dim row_j As Integer
Dim Start_row As Integer
Dim End_row As Integer

With Worksheets("a")
    For SearchCol = 1 To LastCol Step 3
        LastRow_date_new = Application.CountA(.Range((.Cells(1, SearchCol)), (.Cells(65536, SearchCol))))
        For row_i = 2 To LastRow_date_new
            If Sheets("a").Cells(row_i, SearchCol).Value = DateMax Then Start_row = row_i
        Next row_i
        For row_j = LastRow_date_new To 2 Step -1
            If Sheets("a").Cells(row_j, SearchCol).Value = Date_end Then End_row = row_j
        Next row_j
        ''''''' use range col1, row i to col2, row j to copy into new sheet
        Call copy_to_b(Start_row, SearchCol, End_row)
    Next SearchCol
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `For row_j = LastRow_date_new To 2 Step -1`, and after every `For`, you will have your variable equals to last value + step, this is how the `For`-loop exit itself.

So if you don't won't to have that variable to 1, you must set it to the right value after your `For`-loop, something like this :

```
    For row_i = 2 To LastRow_date_new
        If Sheets("a").Cells(row_i, SearchCol).Value = DateMax Then Start_row = row_i
    Next row_i
    row_i=2
    For row_j = LastRow_date_new To 2 Step -1
        If Sheets("a").Cells(row_j, SearchCol).Value = Date_end Then End_row = row_j
    Next row_j
    row_j=2
```

To exit the loop when your criteria is matched, you can use `Exit For`, some would say it's not elegant but it does work (and another way below code reviewed)

```
Sub select_date_range(LastCol As Long, LastRow_date_new As Long, DateMax As Date, Date_end As Date)
Dim SearchCol As Integer
Dim row_i As Integer
Dim row_j As Integer
Dim Start_row As Integer
Dim End_row As Integer

With Worksheets("a")
    For SearchCol = 1 To LastCol Step 3
        LastRow_date_new = Application.CountA(.Range((.Cells(1, SearchCol)), (.Cells(65536, SearchCol))))

        For row_i = 2 To LastRow_date_new
            If CDate(.Cells(row_i, SearchCol).Value) <> CDate(DateMax) Then
            Else
                Start_row = row_i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next row_i

        For row_j = LastRow_date_new To 2 Step -1
            If CDate(.Cells(row_j, SearchCol).Value) <> CDate(Date_end) Then
            Else
                End_row = row_j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next row_j


        ''''''' use range col1, row i to col2, row j to copy into new sheet
        Call copy_to_b(Start_row, SearchCol, End_row)
    Next SearchCol
End With

End Sub
```

To replace your `For`, you can use `Do While` ou `Do Until` :

```
row_j = LastRow_date_new
Do While row_j >= 2 And .Cells(row_j, SearchCol).Value <> Date_end
    row_j = row_j - 1
Loop
End_row = row_j
```

Comment: Thanks @R3uK. I made a mistake in the original question (now edited). I pass the variable `end_row` which is set based on `row_j`. Cheers

Comment: Yup, I saw that afterwards typing and I forgot to correct, done! ;)
Is the code working properly?

Comment: I am still getting a value of 0 for `End_row`, so not yet

Comment: With the `Exit For` method?? As you are comparing dates, maybe use `CDate()` function on both parts of comparaison, see edit

Comment: Ah, it seems an earlier function was resetting the Date_max value, which may have been causing the trouble. the Exit for method now appears to work (mainly). I'll do a bit more debugging...

Comment: Ok so if it moslty work, I'm pretty reassured because this method is pretty classical, I use a bit less often the `Do...Loop` so I might have an offset of one line, but not with the `For...Exit For`. Anyway, glad I could help! Good luck with your debbuging

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your problem may occur due to the absence of any values or only one value in a column that you review. Also, you may miss values if you have null values in this column, if this is the case, I will change my answer. You should change

```
With Worksheets("a")
    For SearchCol = 1 To LastCol Step 3
        LastRow_date_new = Application.CountA(.Range((.Cells(1, SearchCol)), (.Cells(65536, SearchCol))))
        For row_i = 2 To LastRow_date_new
            If Sheets("a").Cells(row_i, SearchCol).Value = DateMax Then Start_row = row_i
        Next row_i
        For row_j = LastRow_date_new To 2 Step -1
            If Sheets("a").Cells(row_j, SearchCol).Value = Date_end Then End_row = row_j
        Next row_j
        ''''''' use range col1, row i to col2, row j to copy into new sheet
        Call copy_to_b(Start_row, SearchCol, End_row)
    Next SearchCol
End With
```

To this

```
Dim xlws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lngrow as Long
Set xlws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("a")
For SearchCol = 1 to LastCol Step 3
    While xlws.Range.Cells(lngrow,SearchCol).Value <> ""
          If xlws.Cells(lngrow,SearchCol).Value = DateMax Then
             Start_row = lngrow
          Elseif xlws.Cells(lngrow,SearchCol).Value = Date_end Then
             End_row = lngrow
          End If
          lngrow = lngrow + 1
     Loop
     Call copy_to_b(Start_row, SearchCol, End_row)
 Next SearchCol
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @cronos2546. I should have mentioned there are no blanks or null values in the column I search. question edited to reflect this. Cheers